# change the Icon Color or delete it

Tags: flutter, dart

I have these containers to select some images. When the user selects the image it covers the whole container so I want the child (ICONS) to be transparent after the image is selected.

```
InkWell(
                          onTap: () async {
                            XFile? image3 = await _picker.pickImage(
                                source: ImageSource.gallery);

                            if (image3 == null) {
                              debugPrint("got null");
                              return;
                            }
                            final image =
                                Image.memory(await image3.readAsBytes());
                            decorationImage3 = DecorationImage(
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              image: image.image,
                            );
                            setState(() {});
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 4 - 25,
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 4 - 25,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.blue.shade900,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                              image: decorationImage3,
                            ),
                            child: const Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                        ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead

```
child: (image3 == null)?Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white):Sizedbox.shrink();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track if an image is selected like this :

```
bool isIMGpicked = false;

...

if (image3 == null) {
         setState(() {
             isIMGpicked = true;
          });
 
       debugPrint("got null");
       return;
}
```

then you can do 1 of these option to make the button disapear

```
Visibility(child :const Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white),visible : isIMGpicked)
```

or this (but the button will still work) :

```
Icon(Icons.add, color: isIMGpicked?Colors.transparent:Colors.white)
```

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: what happends when you use visibility widget ? Maybe you have the boolean inside the build method

Comment: I edited the answear I had forgotten the setState Method , now it propably works